# Uploading image from ios to web service gives 'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array'

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, web-services

I am attempting to upload an image from ios app to web api service.

I am encoding the image using [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions]  then combining into an object with some other data and then using NSJSONSerialization and then placing it in the body of a NSMutableURLRequest as a 'PUT' and then using a NSURLSession to send it off to an asp.net web api service.

The data arrives at the web service and is deserialized using JavaScriptSerializer.  I then use Convert.FromBase64String to recreate the image. However the Convert.FromBase64String is throwing an exception **'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array'**.  The size of the image is 38988 bytes.

To check this out, instead of sending image I send an array containing 'a','b','c', ' ', '=', 'f' (and other characters in various combinations).  This works perfectly, no exception is thrown by Convert.FromBase64String.

What could it be about the image data that is causing this issue?

Simplified Xcode

```
  NSString* const Folder = @"SomeFolder";

  NSString *fileName = [self getFileName];
  NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.0);
  // static char initArray[6] = {'a','b','\0',' ','e','f'};  // if i use this then it works
  // NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:initArray length:6];
  NSString* sData = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

  // set up session
  NSError *error;
  NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
  NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<service url>/api/Documents/PutDoc/%@", id]];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

  NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:Folder, @"folder", fileName, @"fileName", sData, @"sImage", nil];
  NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];

  NSMutableData *postData = (NSMutableData*)[@"=" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  [postData appendData:jsonData];
  [request setHTTPBody:postData];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
  [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  [request addValue:@"*/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

  // send request
  NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
      if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {
        NSString* msg = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Document Saved to server"];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Document Saved" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
      } else {
        NSDictionary* dic = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
        NSString* msg = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Server Error. Code: %d", [httpResponse statusCode]];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Document Not Saved" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
      }
    });
  }];
```

web api c# code (simplified)

```
  JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  Document doc = (Document)js.Deserialize<Document>(value);
  byte[] img;
  try {
    img = Convert.FromBase64String(doc.sImage);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // this is where the 'invalid length' exception is throw
    MyLib.LogIt(string.Format("Error converting: {0}", e.Message));
    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) {
      Content = new StringContent("Could not convert image to binary"),
      ReasonPhrase = "Conversion Error"
    });
  }
    ..
```

Comment: Cross platform character issues could be one culprit. try posting to your api via a dummy app and see if it would accept encoded data from windows without an issue.

Comment: Another consideration: the original base64 requires a CRLF every 72 chars. Maybe your encoder does not add them while your decoder requires them. Usually this can be set via options. Check the encoder/decoder options. Note: your test might work because it is less than 72 bytes.

Comment: Ok, after much testing I have discovered that the issue is that '+' chars within the encoded image were being changed to spaces.  I naively didn't think this would happen because I was placing the data in the body of the PUT. I am confused why the error was 'illegal length' and not 'incorrect format' or similar. Even though it is very ugly my solution is to replace all spaces with + chars on the web service side and this works for all images so far. I know that there are better options (eg stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding) but I am still unsure of a solution that will match both ends.

Answer (score 0):

I am sending selected Image to server using below code and it's working fine for me.

```
-(void)ImageUpdatewithImageID
{
imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImage);
NSString *strParameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.rmsDbController.globalDict objectForKey:@"BranchID"]];
NSString *strPar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[strPar stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request appendPostData:imageData];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailed:)];
 [request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)uploadFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
        // after image successfully uploaded
}
- (void)uploadFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
        // if image not uploaded
}
```